# How to compile php module in php8.0 that used to use TSRMLS_CC in php7, but is deprecated in php8.0

Tags: php, php-extension, php-8

I have a php module that is build for php7 and i think php5 also, but in php8.0 when i try to run `make` i get a long list with errors because of TSRMLS_CC is beeing deprecated.

The errors that are beeing displayed look like:

```
/home/appie/Downloads/php-sweph/sweph.c: In function ‘zif_swe_calc_ut’:
/home/appie/Downloads/php-sweph/sweph.c:512:44: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘TSRMLS_CC’
  512 |  if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "dll",
      |                                            ^~~~~~~~~
/home/appie/Downloads/php-sweph/sweph.c:512:6: error: too few arguments to function ‘zend_parse_parameters’
  512 |  if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "dll",
```

I have many function that use this TSRMLS_CC and they all look like this:

```
PHP_FUNCTION(swe_calc_ut)
{
    char *arg = NULL;
    int rc;
    long ipl, iflag;
    double tjd_ut, xx[6];
    char serr[AS_MAXCH]; 
    int i;

    if(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() != 3) WRONG_PARAM_COUNT;
    
        if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "dll",
            &tjd_ut, &ipl, &iflag) == FAILURE) {
        return;
    }

    rc = swe_calc_ut(tjd_ut, (int)ipl, (int)iflag, xx, serr);

    /* create an array */
    array_init(return_value);
    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        add_index_double(return_value, i, xx[i]);
        add_assoc_string(return_value, "serr", serr);
        add_assoc_long(return_value, "rc", rc);
    }
```

My first thought was, what happens if i remove the TSRMLS_CC. After removal the compiling got finished and i could install the module into apache. Basicly the module works without problems now, but in the log of apache2. I get a long list of warnings from all the functions that use TSRMLS_CC.

They look like:

```
PHP Warning:  Missing arginfo for swe_calc() in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Missing arginfo for swe_calc_ut() in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Missing arginfo for swe_fixstar() in Unknown on line 0
```

How do i get rid of the warnings, is there are alternative for TSRMLS_CC? I am trying to understand it, but was not able to solve it yet.

Answer (score 4):

A summary of changes to the internals can always be found in the [UPGRADING.INTERNALS](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-8.0/UPGRADING.INTERNALS) file in the PHP source code.

The two changes you've encountered are unrelated:

- `TSRMLS_CC` was part of the the Thread-Safe Resource Manager, an implementation of thread-local storage used to build PHP for multi-threaded environments. It has been removed because newer mechanisms exist to do the same thing much more transparently. You can safely remove all uses of `TSRMLS_*` from your extension, unless you need to retain PHP 5 support.
- `arginfo` is the information about a function's parameter names and types which is used for reflection. It used to be optional, but is now required, partly to enable all functions to be callable with the new named parameters syntax. The easiest way to generate it is to write "stub" PHP definitions - empty PHP functions with the right signature but no implementation, similar to what you might define to make auto-complete work in an IDE. You can then pass that PHP file to the [gen-stub.php](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/build/gen_stub.php) script. This is how the `arginfo` for all the bundled PHP extensions is now managed, so you can find lots of examples if you look around the source code, including in [the skeleton extension](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/ext/skeleton).

Comment: How write stub php definitions and how do use/run the gen-stub.php script?

Comment: @Arjan See updated answer. I think the script just takes the name of a file or directory to process as a command-line parameter.

Comment: @NikiC Thanks for the edit. Let me know if I've got any details wrong!  :)